# Height-balanced tree understanding zero input test case

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to solve one algorithmic problem from leetcode.

> Given a binary tree, determine if it is height-balanced.
>
> For this problem, a height-balanced binary tree is defined as:
>
> a binary tree in which the depth of the two subtrees of every node
>   never differ by more than 1.

My approach is to collect the depths of the nodes and compare them. When the difference is smaller than 1 (abs), then return 1, else return False. When there is not root replace it with 0.

```py
class Solution(object):
    def isBalanced(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: bool
        """
        if not root or not root.left and not root.right:
            return 0
        a = self.isBalanced(root.left)
        b = self.isBalanced(root.right)
        if abs(a-b)<=1:
            return 1 + max(a,b)
        else:
            return False
        return True
```

Unfortunately, the solution fails on a very primitive [] empty test input. Which is unclear to me. I thought that when there are no children, there's nothing to compare, hence 0. Am I missing smth from the definition of height-balanced tree?

Comment: From my understanding if the test case is `[]`, it is balanced since there are no children. The same logic holds true if it is just a root such as `[5]`. There are no children so it is 'balanced' on both the right and left sides of the tree. I think the definition is that the height is based on the left/right children so having no tree is balanced

Comment: @nathancy so this is more about definition then?

Comment: I would assume so. The prompt is vague about base cases such as a zero or one input test case and is probably something that you would ask for clarification if you encountered this problem in an interview